# Oracle sql joining derived table with union

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like this:

```
select       product_code,
             count(foo.container_id) as "quantity_of_containers",
             max((trunc(foo.update_date - foo.creation_date))) as "max_days"
from product
inner join stock on stock.product_id = product.product_id
inner join (
 select arch.container_id,
        arch.creation_date,
        arch.update_date
from arch
union all
select 
        container.container_id,
        container.creation_date,
        container.update_date
from container) foo on stock.container_id = foo.container_id
group by product_code
order by "max_days" desc
```

the question is what is wrong with this query, when i run it, it seems okay but after further inspection it looks like only records from container are there, for some reason there is not a single record from arch table. Is there different way to write this query with same logic behind it?  i need to get records from both arch and container since one table is archive and another is current table. Also approach with unioning two separate queries on container and arch is working but i was looking for something faster.

@edit:
im sending some sample data to make it more clear what i have actually meant.

```
+---------------+----------+----------+
| product_code  | quantity | max_days |
+---------------+----------+----------+
| 5999990024965 |      345 |       85 |
| 5999990027614 |      326 |       81 |
| 5999990023753 |       87 |       77 |
+---------------+----------+----------+
```

data from arch table,

```
+---------------+----------+----------+
| product_code  | quantity | max_days |
+---------------+----------+----------+
| 5999990082415 |       11 |       84 |
| 5999990059615 |        2 |       58 |
| 5999990023470 |        1 |       41 |
+---------------+----------+----------+
```

data from container table.

However when i run query i've pasted here i only got records from container table,

 and yes stock.container_id really matches foo.container_ids (arch and container)

Comment: Do you have data in arch table or do you have container_id in arch table which matches the container id in stock table?

Comment: We can't see your tables or data. Can you add some representative sample data that demonstrates the problem so we can recreate it? I'd guess your `arch` records have container IDs that are not in `stock`, but it can only be a guess...

Comment: Yep, seems like a data-related issue and not query-related. Your query looks fine for what you need it to do.

Comment: table arch is exactly same table as table container, the only difference is that arch table contains archived records, if it has any value to anyone its oracle 11g. Arch/container tables contain a lot of ids for joining different tables and also creation dates, update dates etc. I have data and container_id in arch table which matches container_id in stock. The thing that makes me wonder is why this query creates different result than unioned queries on separated arch and container tables. Thanks for every reply anyway!

Comment: Provide some sample data for us to somehow reproduce your issue so that we can possibly find a solution. :)

Comment: @MichałMaroń and for the arch+stock rows, are there corresponding rows in the product table? Given what you've said, I suspect not. Also, how do you know you aren't getting rows from the arch table?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer, but it's too long to go in a comment.

What do you get when you run the following query?

```
select *
from product
inner join stock on stock.product_id = product.product_id
inner join (
 select arch.container_id,
        arch.creation_date,
        arch.update_date,
        'arch' qry
from arch
union all
select 
        container.container_id,
        container.creation_date,
        container.update_date,
        'container' qry
from container) foo on stock.container_id = foo.container_id
where foo.qry = 'arch';
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm really sorry but it seems like the reason was software bug? after server restart query provided needed data. Thanks everyone for your time, seems like first query was actually correct.

Really sorry for taking your time, thank you everyone.